# How to override body_listener:array_normalizer for cetain urls in FOSRestBundle symfony

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

I am using this configuration

```
fos_rest:
    param_fetcher_listener: true
    body_listener:
        array_normalizer: fos_rest.normalizer.camel_keys
```

It works well and helps to convert client request parameters to form/object properties.

But in some cases, I am not using forms, I want to keep parameters separated with underscores. I dont want above setting to be applied to some urls.

How do I override (disable) above setting on per route basis (annotation or some rules for url patter would be best).

Comment: how about my solution? You solved your problem already?

Comment: Hi, zone feature sounds interesting, but yeah I have already solved the problem by implementing custom array_normalizer which can exclude url patterns. I will post the code in my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with disabling/enabling all fos/rest-bundle listeners per some url's then you can use `zones` feature (from 2.0 release).

```
fos_rest:
    zone:
        - { path: ^/route/with/listeners/enabled/* }
```

Docs: http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/3-listener-support.html

If you have more time then maybe you can help to improve that feature - here is nice RFC - https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/pull/1152